# how to use variable from one robot file into another robot file in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Here is example 
add.robot file

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SudsLibrary
Library   XML
Library   String

*** Test Cases ***
Test Webservice

    create Soap Client    http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

    ${add}    Create Wsdl Object   Add
    ${add.intA}    Set Variable    3
    ${add.intB}    Set Variable    4

    # # call soap web service
    call soap method  Add  ${Add}
    ${soap_response}    Get Last Received
    log to console  ${soap_response}
    ${XML_object}=  Parse XML  ${soap_response}
    log    ${XML_object}
    ${result}  get element text  ${XML_object}  .//AddResult
    set global variable  ${result}
```

substract.robot file

trying to use result variable into this file but its showing error. 
Both file exist in same folder

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SudsLibrary
Library   XML
Library   String


*** Test Cases ***
Test Webservice
    create Soap Client    http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

    ${subs}    Create Wsdl Object   Subtract
    ${subs.intA}    Set Variable   ${result} #shows error
    ${subs.intB}    Set Variable    4

    # # call soap web service
    call soap method  Subtract  ${subs}
    ${soap_response}    Get Last Received
    log to console  ${soap_response}
    ${XML_object}=  Parse XML  ${soap_response}
    log    ${XML_object}
    ${result11}=  get element text  ${XML_object}  .//SubtractResult
```

Comment: Please see the changed example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. 
Value form Test 1.robot is used in Test 2.robot

Test 1.robot

```
*** keywords ***
Test1 Webservice
   set global variable  ${node}
```

Test 2.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Resource Test 1.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Test2 Webservice
  Test 1.Test1Webservice
  ${node1} set Variable ${node}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a best practice to make each file independent, so I would encourage you to rewrite your tests so that they aren't dependent on each other.

### Global Robot Variables

That being said, if you want to set a variable in one file and be able to use it in another, you need to use the built-in keyword [Set global variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable).

From the documentation:

> Variables set with this keyword are globally available in all test cases and suites executed after setting them. Setting variables with this keyword thus has the same effect as creating from the command line using the options --variable or --variablefile. Because this keyword can change variables everywhere, it should be used with care.

Your question mentions `var1` but your code doesn't have `var1`. If you meant to write `${node}` (which appeared in the original version of your question), you would do it like this:

```
set global variable  ${node}
```

### Global library scope

If you're not asking about a robot variable, but rather how to have your library keep hold of a variable between suites, you need to set the `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` variable in your library to `"GLOBAL"`. For example:

```
class token1:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"
    ...
```

For more information see [Test library scope](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope)

Comment: I have tried to use global variable in one robot file and mentioned it in another file.it says variable definition  not found.

Comment: @madhur: then you are doing something wrong. Without seeing something more specific, we can't help you.  Without a doubt, global variables work in robot framework tests.

Comment: I have added two file in link ,i want to use variable result from add.robot to another file substract.robot  please refer if you have time, click on downlaod 1.  https://ufile.io/h7vta       2.  https://ufile.io/ttp0b

Comment: @madhur: please don't link to external files. Edit your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: add.robot file ...set global variable ${result}  10   then subtract.robot file there is one variable  value1   ${result}

Comment: set global variable does not work if it under *** test case *** as shown in above example

Comment: @madhur: that is incorrect. `set global variable` does work in a test case, exactly like I show in the answer (assuming `${node}` exists)

Comment: I used the global variable in line 5 of add.robot ( set global variable ${result}) under *** variable*** section then i tried to use  this variable(result) into substract.robot , it shows error

Comment: You must have done something wrong. The code in my answer absolutely will work. What does the error tell you? You also have to make sure add.ronot runs before subtract.robot.

Comment: I executed add.robot first then substract.robot , it says in variable definition is not found for ${result} variable of substract.robot

Comment: @madhur I don't see anywhere where you call `set global variable` in add.robot.

Comment: sorry to missed out , i didn't update here.i run this code on pycharm , it shows variable defination not found error.